# Control duplicado en combos dependientes con ShtumiUsefulBundle en Symfony2

Tags: doctrine, symfony2

Ésta es mi sección en el config del aplicativo:

```
shtumi_useful :
dependent_filtered_entities:
    ciudad_by_dpto:
        class: GestionBundle:Ciudad
        parent_property: dpto
        property: nombreciud
        role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        no_result_msg: 'No hay regiones encontradas'
        order_property: nombreciud
        order_direction: ASC
```

Éste es mi `configureFormFields`:

```
$formMapper
        ->add('nombre')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('urlcurriculum')
        ->add('cargo')
        ->add('departamento')

        ->add('ciudad', 'shtumi_dependent_filtered_entity', array(
            'entity_alias' => 'ciudad_by_dpto',
            'empty_value' => 'Select',
            'parent_field' => 'departamento',
            'required' => true,

        ))
    ;
```

Al cargar la página funciona perfecto la dependencia de los combos pero resulta que el combo de ciudad sale duplicado, la verdad no sé cómo o por qué se está duplicando, adjunto un pantallazo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]